# Python dates: How to check if a particular day (mm/dd/yy) is in the next week or month?

Tags: python, date

Let's say I have a dictionary with dates as values. I want to find any and all dates that are in next week's range and next month's range. For instance, if today is Thursday and I am looking for next week's dates, I want all the dates from this coming Monday to next Sunday (a full week), and if today's month is July, I want all the dates in August.

Here's my current code attempt at next month:

```
num_d = {‘random next month day’: '08/28/17', ‘just another day’: '08/23/17’,
‘next week day’: ’07/18/17’, ‘not in next week’: ’07/25/17’}

current_date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
# 07/13/17

for key in num_d:
    if (num_d[key])[:2] == current_date[:2] and (num_d[key])[-2:] == current_date[-2:]:
```

The reason I stopped is that my current naive code doesn't take into account when a year ends and a new year begins (December to January of next year), and I want to find a smarter way to do this than by making case statements.

For next week dates, is there a way to take into account today's date and which day of the week it is, and return all the dates between the coming Monday and next Sunday as mentioned above? such that for today, Thursday 07/13/17 the dates return range from 07/17/17 to 07/24/17 and not 07/20/17 to 07/27/17?

Comment: `if date < current_date + one_week:`? Use *actual datetime objects*, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe mentions, use actual datetime objects. Here I define a `is_next_week` / `is_next_month` method. Both use `datetime.strptime` to convert your strings to datetime objects.

The next week checker uses `date.isocalendar()[1]` to get the week numbers and then checks if the difference is exactly one.

The next month checker uses `date.month` to get the months and then checks if the difference is exactly one.

```
from datetime import *

def is_next_week(date_str):
  new_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%m/%d/%y").date()
  today_date = datetime.today()
  return (new_date.isocalendar()[1] - today_date.isocalendar()[1]) + (new_date.year - today_date.year) * today_date.isocalendar()[1]   == 1

def is_next_month(date_str):
  new_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%m/%d/%y").date()
  today_date = datetime.today()
  return (new_date.month - today_date.month) + (new_date.year - today_date.year) * today_date.month == 1


num_d = {'random next month day': '08/28/17', 
          'just another day': '08/23/17', 
          'next week day': '07/18/17', 
          'not in next week': '07/25/17'}

print "Date     Week  Month"
for key in num_d:
    print num_d[key], is_next_week(num_d[key]), is_next_month(num_d[key])
```

Run it [here](https://repl.it/J1It/2)

As @jonsharpe points out we need to deal with the end of the year; if there is an overflow, we simply add the last week/month to our total.

For instance, when the week overflows from 53 to 1, the total is computed as:

```
1 -           53 +        (1 *        53)
new_week      old_week    years_diff  old_week
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, not sure why you were downvoted

Comment: What if next month is January? This has similar naivety problems to the strings the OP used.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry ignore previous comment, that was false. How exactly do you implement this? I am confused because I thought 53 would represent the new first week in January. EDIT: I think I figured it out. Thank you both.